# Can One Give Away an Aliya?

Tags: halacha, synagogue, torah-service

If one is offered  an Aliya, can he give the honor to someone else? By “offered” I mean the Gabbai issues the Aliyas prior to the Torah service in the form of, say, a card with number of the Aliya printed on it. The recipient could of course accept the honor or decline it. If he accepts, can he make a unilateral decision to give the honor to someone else?   Would the answer change if the Gabbai calls people to the bimah during the Torah reading?

Comment: Are you asking halachically, or about synagogue policy?

Comment: @alex.  I mean  halakhacally and ethically. If the answer depends on synagogue policy, I suppose you may have answered the question

Comment: One is not supposed to refuse am aliyah, unless they would be embarrassed

Comment: There are some people who cannot get (or to whom it's customary to not give) certain _aliyos_. For example, anyone immediately after his son got an _aliya_, or a non-Jew. The _gabay_ is entrusted by the synagogue with ensuring such rules and customs are followed. The _aliya_ honoree is not. Therefore, I'd say it's unwise and should be against synagogue policy for the honoree to pass the honor to someone of his choosing. I'm not sure whether this answers your question.

Comment: It's a regular practice among _mizrachim_ to bid on an _aliyah_ and give it away to a friend.

Comment: @Kazibácsi. I’ve seen that done in Ashkenazi synagogues on the High Holy Days. Do Mizrachim bid on aliyot on regular Sabbaths?

Comment: In my experience, I would even say that it is more common to give it away both on Shabbatot and on holidays.

Comment: @JJLL Assuming you mean Edot Ha’mizrach by “*mizrachim*”, and not “Mizrachnekim”, I’d comment that from the dozen or so Sephardic synagogues that I frequent I’ve never seen any of them sell *aliyot* on a regular Shabbat; same for Ashkenazim.